# Can't create new "enterprise" project in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, ubuntu, glassfish

I'm running netbeans 6.7.1 on Ubuntu Karmic.

On the services tab I added a new glassfish v3 prelude server, I installed it to my home directory using the download button. I started the server and opened localhost:4848 to verify I can get into the admin panel.

Then I did file->new projct and created a new java web->web application. On the configuration step of the wizard it preselected glassfish v3 prelude and java ee 5. I accepted and did a test run. I ran the project just fine.

So now I did file->new projecct and attempted to create a Java EE->ejb module. When I arrive to the server configuration stage of the wizard, it doesn't show any servers on the server dropdown list (so it's empty), it also doesn't see any version of java on the "java ee version" dropdown list. This also happens for the other "Java EE" project types.

I can't seem to get my head around why I can make a new web application but not an ejb module.

Can anyone provide any insight to why it might not be seeing that I have java or glassfish installed when I try to make a new java ee project but I see it when I try to make a java web project?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an EJB project that targets GlassFish v3 Prelude because Prelude doesn't support EJB deployment, without installing the optional EJB container.

You should install NB 6.8 and GlassFish v3, since v3 does support EJB deployment, without the need to install additional optional modules.

If you MUST use NB 6.7.1, you should read this [article about the v3 enabler](http://blogs.oracle.com/vkraemer/entry/experimental_features_marker) and try it.